# Solr query long execution time for multiple ORs

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I have a question regarding solr queries.
My query basically contains thousand of OR conditions for authors (author:name1 OR author:name2 OR author:name3 OR author:name4 ...)
The execution time on my index is huge (around 15 sec). When i tag all the associated documents with a custom field and value like authorlist:1 and then i change my query to just search for authorlist:1 it executes in 78 ms. How come there is such a big difference in exec-time?
Can somebody please explain why there is sucha difference (maybe the query parser?) and if there is a way to speed this up?

Thx for the help

Comment: Try author:(name1 name2 name3 name4 name5) with `q.op=OR` - but the issue is that in your simple example (`authorlist:1`) only a single value needs to be looked up and cached, while in your extended example, thousand++ lookups for document ids has to be performed, then merged to generate the final set of documents (and possibly scored and sorted).

Comment: You should try this with join
Create a temp document in solr contain author name you want then query it with that document you will get result much faster than now. < https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join >